# Visudo - Change user without password doesn't work

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, password, visudo

I want a user to be able to change to another user without a password and any other root rights. I followed already a hint on https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82438/allow-sudo-to-another-user-without-password but it didn't work for me.

I've edited the sudoers with visudo and added following line:

```
test1 ALL=(test2:test2) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

I've tried also:

```
test1 ALL=(test2) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

But if I try to change to this user as user test1 with:

```
sudo su test2
```

I get always a prompt for a password of user test1. If I type the password I get the error `Sorry, user test1 is not allowed to execute '/bin/su -u test2' as root on host.example.com`

Well, I've searched already through Google & Co but I find only the way above with the entry in the sudoers which doesn't work actually.

I hope somebody can help me :-)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have already found the solution:

```
sudo -u test2 bash
```